# Testng XmlSuite.getAllParameters() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, testng

While running the scripts, it run the tests properly but at the end when it loads the XmlSuite and generate reports, It throws NullPointerException.
FYI,
 - This is an intermittent issue, as sometimes it fails to generate reports.
 - I am using customised html reporting technique to generate reports.
 - 6.11 : This is TestNg version, i am using in my code.

If you check the following link, [cbeust/testng changes](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt), similar kind of issue got resolved in TestNG updated version 6.9.13 **'NullPointerException on loading XmlSuites programmatically'**

Please comment and let me know, if you require more info.
**Error:**

```
  org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.testng.xml.XmlSuite.getAllParameters(XmlSuite.java:416)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:352)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:177)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:105)
        ... 9 more
```

**Surefire plugin Configuration:**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration><argLine>-Xmx3072m</argLine></configuration>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </plugin>
```

**Suite File:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Prod suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="100">

<listeners>
        <listener class-name="xyz.listener.AnnotationTransformer"/>
      <listener class-name="xyz.listener.TestListener"/>
  </listeners>

    <test name="Prod - OSCAR Locale-US-Set1 Browser-chrome"
        preserve-order="true">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[(groups.containsKey("PVT") || (groups.containsKey("PVT") && groups.containsKey("INCLUDE_US_ONLY"))) && 
                                                    !(groups.containsKey("EXCLUDE_US")) && 
                                                    !(groups.containsKey("INCLUDE_UK_ONLY")) && 
                                                    !(groups.containsKey("INCLUDE_AU_ONLY")) &&
                                                    !(groups.containsKey("INCLUDE_CN_ONLY")) && 
                                                    !(groups.containsKey("INCLUDE_JP_ONLY"))]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <parameter name="browser" value="" />
        <parameter name="country" value="us" />
        <parameter name="language" value="en" />
        <parameter name="env" value="" />

        <classes>
            <class
                name="xyz" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

```java
protected void generateFailureSuite(XmlSuite xmlSuite, ISuite suite, String outputDir) { 
    // XmlSuite failedSuite = (XmlSuite) xmlSuite.clone(); 
    XmlSuite failedSuite = xmlSuite.shallowCopy(); 
    // failedSuite.setName("[" + xmlSuite.getName() + "]"); 
    failedSuite.setName("Failed suite [" + xmlSuite.getName() + "]"); 
    m_xmlSuite = failedSuite; 
    if (null != failedSuite.getTests() && failedSuite.getTests().size() > 0) { 
        // create testng-failed.xml file to any dir 
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code in the description. Also go through this link on how to ask a good question on this forum : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please retry using the latest released version of TestNG `6.14.3`. If the problem still exists, please edit your question and add a sample that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Alok : Thanks for the suggestion. As this is first time i have posted question on [link](https://stackoverflow.com),  i am unaware of formatting and way to ask of good question.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan :- FYI, this is an intermittent issue. Talking about code, It is a big framework and in error also the any java class is not specified, so cann't think, what code should i paste. Please guide.                                                                            
But FYI, firstly, when I am using TestNG 6.8.8, with this code line somewhere "xmlSuite.clone()" in code. it is working fine. Now with TestNG 6.11, I am using xmlSuite.shallowCopy(), and it is throwing above error.

Comment: @NandkishorPeriwal - The code you should be pasting would ideally be your `suite` file and your `surefire plugin` configuration (if you are working with maven) and the surefire plugin version. You are also mentioning that you are using `xmlSuite.shallowCopy()`. Where are you using? Please feel free to add as much as information as possible to help us, help you out. Else its going to be difficult. Lastly, please use `6.14.3` (latest released version as of today). Bugs in earlier version could very well have been fixed with this.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan - Have added the suite file and surefire plugin configuration. Below is the code where i am generating testng customized report and using shallowCopy.
And regarding testng Version 6.14.3, first, is it stable version. second after upgrading, there are some compatibility issues with other plugings i will check on that side too.

Comment: protected void generateFailureSuite(XmlSuite xmlSuite, ISuite suite,
String outputDir) {
// XmlSuite failedSuite = (XmlSuite) xmlSuite.clone();
XmlSuite failedSuite = xmlSuite.shallowCopy();
// failedSuite.setName("[" + xmlSuite.getName() + "]");
failedSuite.setName("Failed suite [" + xmlSuite.getName() + "]");
m_xmlSuite = failedSuite;

if (null != failedSuite.getTests() && failedSuite.getTests().size() > 0) {
 // create testng-failed.xml file to any dir
}

Comment: @NandkishorPeriwal - Assuming that this is a bug with `6.11`, how do you think it would be fixed? You obviously would need to use the latest released version. And yes its stable AFAIK (I am one of the contributors for TestNG). So I would request you to please retry using `6.14.3` and post your results. I dont think this issue has got anything to do with the listeners because it seems to be coming from surefire directly (atleast that is what the stacktrace suggests)

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan - Apologies for the late response krishnan. As this issue was causing a lot of problem so i decided not to use upgraded testng version that time. But now I need to upgrade Testng version. I appreciate your response and used the latest version of TestNG - 6.14.3 but no luck. I have tried a few combinations of Surefire (latest) and Testng too but no success.

Comment: The thing I observed is if I run test cases single threaded then no NPE issue is coming else as soon as I use parallel="tests" I get this error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @NandkishorPeriwal - The latest released version of TestNG is `7.0.0-beta1`. Can you please try using that ? If the problem persists, request you to please edit your question and share a sample that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan - Thanks Mahadevan for the quick reply. I have tried with the TestNG version [tag:7.0.0-beta1] too but no success (used many surefire version too in parallel).   As the issue is intermittent so i cannot say how it could be reproduced but what i found on online is below .  **The important thing to remember with the parallel option is: the concurrency happens within the same JVM process. That is efficient in terms of memory and execution time, but you may be more vulnerable towards race conditions or other unexpected and hard to reproduce behavior.**

Comment: Without a sample reproducible project I don't think I can do anything more to help dig in.

Comment: Also i can say that if I do not use [FailedReporter TestNG Listener](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/FailedReporter.java) I do not get this NPE issue.